# Detecting a unsigned integer overflow in a c function

Tags: c

How to detect overflow in a function when n becomes greater than 64 bits?

```
uint64_t col(uint64_t n) 
{
    int count = 0;

    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else {
            n = (3 * n) + 1;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What operations are you running that might overflow?  Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Please edit your code into the question and format it properly.

Comment: @dbush I have included it my question. What if n becomes greater than 64 bits during the while loop and how can I detect it in this case?

Comment: thank you ill do that next time @DavidGrayson

Comment: Save a copy of `n` before doing math, then compare new result with former. If the new is minor than the copy you overflowed the variable.

Comment: They aren't needed for this super simple example, but GCC and Clang have builtins like `__builtin_add_overflow` and `__builtin_mul_overflow` that let you do an arithmetic operations in a safe way while detecting overflows:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Comment: Why have you made your question essentially useless by deleting the whole body?

Comment: @angelina: your question is useful and the answers will help other programmers with the same problem. Contributors spend time writing up answers for to help everyone improve their skills, there is no reason to remove useful contents, you raised a legitimate question and the answer is not obvious to everyone...

Comment: @chqrlie I just thought it was a dumb question and since it has been asked multiple times I thought I'll just delete it. I am new here and I didn't really know how stack overflow works

Comment: @angelina: The question is not a dumb question, there might be duplicates, but these other questions might be subtly different and command different answers. Look at all answers and comments learn from everyone. Enjoy C programming!

Comment: one thing to be wary of, `count` is an `int` but your function returns a `uint64_t`. You should make those types the same, one way or the other. Doesn't look like `count` will ever go negative, so probably make that `uint64_t count;`, or make both the function and `count` `unsigned` if that's big enough.

Comment: @Frankie_C: this method might work for some expressions, but not for this particular one as (3 * n + 1) % (UINT64_MAX+1) might be greater than n with 3 * n + 1 greater than UINT64_MAX. For example `12297829382473034408 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8` -> `18446744073709551609 0xfffffffffffffff9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect *overflow*, or more precisely wrap around, by comparing the value with a computed maximum before the operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t collatz(uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t count = 0;

    if (n == 0) {
        return count;
    }

    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else {
            if (n > (UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3) {
                printf("overflow!\n");
                return UINT64_MAX;
            }
            n = (3 * n) + 1;
        }
        if (count == UINT64_MAX) {
            printf("too many iterations!\n");
            return UINT64_MAX;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Since the function can _legitimately_ return 0, would `return 0;` --> `return UINT64_MAX;` be better as an overflow sentinel value?

Comment: @CraigEstey: good point. If `count` can reach `UINT64_MAX`, it seems obvious that `n` must be part of a cycle that does not include `1`, hence `UINT64_MAX` cannot be a legitimate result for a `uint64_t` argument.

Comment: why have you done (UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3 to detect overflow? @chqrlie

Comment: @angelina: because if `n = (UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3`, the computation will not overflow as the new value will be `UINT64_MAX`, `UINT64_MAX-1` or `UINT64_MAX-2`, and the next value of `n` will produce `UINT64_MAX+1`, `UINT64_MAX+2` or `UINT64_MAX+3`, hence an overflow.  Using the exact values, `n = 0x5555555555555554`, `3 * n + 1 = 18446744073709551613`, which is `UINT64_MAX-2` and the next value produces `UINT64_MAX+1` which wraps around to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `n /= 2;` should never overflow, so I'm not worried about that.

The question I think you're asking is:

*Will `n = (3 * n) + 1;` ever overflow?*

That can be answered as an inequality:

- If `(3 * n) + 1 > UINT64_MAX`, then you have Overflow.

And that is an inequality you can solve algebraically.

- If `(3*n) > UINT64_MAX-1`, then you have Overflow
- If `n > (UINT64_MAX-1)/3`, then you have Overflow

So, ultimately, if `n > (UINT64_MAX-1)/3` (or approximately `6.1489e18`), then you cannot complete the calculation without overflowing `uint64_t`.

Comment: You arrived at the right result, but it's risky to try to apply algebra to C code, since integer division acts differently than division in your math classes.  (Algebra tells us that if n/10 = 0 then n = 0.)  You can apply one definition/property of unsigned integer division, which is that A/B is the largest integer such that (A/B) * B does not exceed B.